# Ionic project creation on windows machine. "Ionic start projectname"

Tags: node.js, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

Finally, I am posting my query here as I have gone through lots of links but unable to get success of it. I am trying to install Ionic & Cordova on my window machine to build sample project as a starter kit. After lots of fight I have installed Ionic and Cordova as I am behind proxy wall. I have installed Ionic and Cordova with npm by using following command:

npm install -g cordova
npm install -g ionic

Now I am trying to create ionic project with help of following cmd:
**npm start ToBe tabs**

but its giving me following error and downloading file from github.com site instead of using local global setup. Anyone have idea about it. Do i have to set any path in my window Environment.

> D:\mypractice\first\ionic>ionic start ToBe tabs
>
> Creating Ionic app in
>   folder D:\mypractice\first\ionic\ToBe based on tabs project
>   Downloading:
>   https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip Error
>   with start Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.113:443
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14) Error Initializing app: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.113:443 
>   Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.113:443
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

Open a command prompt

Run this

**set PROXY=http://myproxy.xyz:80**

Run this

**ionic start myApp tabs**